# Problems defining install-platlib in pydistutils.cfg --

Tags: python

According to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/install/#custom-installation) I should be able to simply define this in my ~/.pydistutils.cfg and be off and running.

```
[install]
install-base=$HOME
install-purelib=python/lib
install-platlib=python/lib.$PLAT
install-scripts=python/scripts
install-data=python/data
```

But - when I do this I simply get this error...

> error: install-base or
>   install-platbase supplied, but
>   installation scheme is incomplete

But I followed the docs explicitly.  Can anyone shed any light on why this is occurring; and how to fix it??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You MUST include this..

```
install-headers=python/??
```

So the final looks like this..

```
[install]
install-base=$HOME
install-purelib=python/lib
install-platlib=python/lib.$PLAT
install-scripts=python/scripts
install-headers=python/include
install-data=python/data
```